# Calculate total number of matrices of all orders which contain $2013$ elements

Tags: matrices, prime-numbers, arithmetic

> Calculate total number of matrices of all orders which contain $2013$ elements

My Try:: By Simple Guessing wecan say that there are two matrices of order

$(1\times 2013)$ and $(2013 \times 1)$

But my question is: How can I check other matrices exist or not, and How can I check whether numbers like $2013$ and $2011$ are prime or not.

Comment: I don't understand how $(1 \times 2013)$ is a matrix.  Seems to me there are a rather large number of matrices having these dimensions... unless they're defined over the field with one element :).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to factor $2013$. A simple start is that because the sum of the digits of $2013$ is divisible by $3$, the number $2013$ is divisible by $3$.

Divide. We get $671$. Is this further divisible? You can test various primes. There is no point in testing $5$; $7$ doesn't work; and we get success at $11$.  Divide. We get $61$.

So $2013=3\cdot 11\cdot 61$. Now can you find the required number?  As a check on your further work, it will turn out that there is a total (including the ones you found) of $8$ possibilities.

**Remark:** The answer to your problem is, as was probably clear to you, the number of positive divisors of $2013$. It can be shown that if $n$ has prime power factorization
$$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k},$$
where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, then $n$ has
$$(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$$
distinct positive divisors.

You do not need this result to solve the $n=2013$ problem, a simple list will do the job.